# (LabVIEW) Using XY-Plot to plot Earth longitude and latitude

Tags: graph, labview

I am new to LabVIEW and I am trying to use XY-Plot to graph Earth longitude and latitude (like the image below)

[image]

However, my code did not work well, nothing appeared except the scaling of x and y axis changed. I cannot see any problem here, could someone help me point out what I did wrong?

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

What you want is very close to [this example](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YGwYCAW&l=en-NZ),

[image: XY-graph]

you have the two 1D arrays already as output of your for-loop, so feed them into a 'bundle' function then into the XY graph.

Most likely the Build XY graph wizard fails with the numerous changes of data types, just because the datatypes are compatible (no broken wires) doesn't mean the conversions work or make sense.